# htaccess to redirect from subdirectory to alternate domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to do a simple task with htaccess but I don't have any experiences with htaccess. Basically, this is what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a website (www.example1.com) with a hosting account. And now, I'm launching a second website (www.example2.com) that uses the same hosting account.

Physically the files for www.example2.com exist in www.example1.com/example2.

As you might expect, what I'm trying to achieve is that when a user writes www.example1.com/example2, they are redirected to www.example2.com.

This is what I've tried doing

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^/example1.com/
RewriteRule !^/example2.com/
```

And also...

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from example2.com
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^example2(.*) http://www.example2.com$1 [R=301, L]
```

First line - check if the host matches example1.com with or without the "www.".

Second line - check if the path starts with example2 and, if it does, redirect to www.example2.com, maintaining any existing path after example2.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply. After doing so, if I go to example1.com/example2, it still doesn't rewrite the URI to example2.com. Any clue why this is happening? Thanks heaps!

Comment: First, did you restart the server after changing the rules? You need to. If that isn't it, I would recommend simplifying the rule so that every request on example1.com redirects to example2.com by changing the RewriteRule to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example2.com$1 [R=301, L]`. If that doesn't work, then it means either your rewrite rules aren't being reached (issue elsewhere in your configuration) or the RewriteCond is not matching example1.com (check for typos). If that rule matches, then it is the example2 path match that is failing and you can work on that part of the rule.